# self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

Hi I have been doing a lot of research now, and used all of their solutions. I am kinda frustrated about this.

I have this in my viewDidLoad to create my rightbarbutton.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"bla"     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(test)];
```

Then I have this method test, for the selector.

```
- (void)test
{
NSLog(@"bla");
}
```

But somehow I always get unrecognized selector and it crashes everytime I press on the button, I even tried to make it with an argument, just to see if it works with a colon.

Comment: Did you implement the `test` method in the same class that has your custom `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue..

1 - Make sure `-(void)test` is defined in your header.

2- If `-(void)test` isn't defined in your header then make sure it is implemented before you use it or make reference to it.

Also, If your not using ARC then your code above is going to leak.

Setting rightBarButtonItem retains the object (+1) and alloc/init (+1) meaning you will always have an extra reference count.

Try..

```
UIBarButtonItem *rbi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"bla" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(test:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rbi;
    [rbi release];
```

Comment: I am using ARC and I also tried to put it in the header file already :S

Comment: Oh, I get another error message when I put the method in the header file. I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Maybe I was too mad about this :P But still doesn't work -.-

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the action like this:

```
-(void) test:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"blah");
}
```

And in your button creation, use @selector(test:) instead.

This is the basic pattern for using the target/action pattern used throughout Cocoa. In some cases, you'll have multiple UI items calling the same action and you'll want to know which object triggered the action.